# Creating column extendable tables in JSF

Tags: primefaces, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I wanna create a table where I should hide some columns. Whenever I click on an arrow or some button The hidden columns should be display along with original columns in that table. 
  For example, I have 20 columns, I don't need show all the columns at the staring point of view. Suppose I want to display 5 columns in UI, renaming 15 should be hidden. Where can I put some arrow on right corner(in header line) of table to extend the table with remaining columns.

Is it possible with JSF with rich-faces or anything else.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far? could you extend your question with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dndColumns.jsf) on primefaces labs. It allows to dynamically add columns to a datatable. I am sure you can tweak it to get the behaviour you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<rich:dataTable.` Set the `rendered` property of the columns which should be initially hidden by using a `boolean` property in your class.

> `<rich:dataTable value="" var="v" id="tbl">`
>              `<rich:column>Always visible column 1</rich:column>`
>              `<rich:column rendered="#{del.renderColumn}">Visible on demand</rich:column>`
>             `<rich:column>Always visible column 2</rich:column>`
>             `<rich:column>Always visible column 3</rich:column>`
>       `</rich:dataTable>`

Use an `<a4j:commandButton` and set the property `renderColumn` as `true` at button action and `reRender` the table.

> `<a4j:commandButton value="Show" action="#{del.renderHiddenColumn()}" reRender="tbl"/>`